# AppStoreConnect, does leaving team sends email to account holder

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

When I leave the team in AppStoreConnect, is there some information sent about this event to account holder or admins? Or is it just removed without any notification?

Answer (score 1):

Apple does send a notification to the account holder and admins of the team. This notification typically comes in the form of an email indicating that a user has left the team. The email might not detail the reasons for the departure but will notify the team's account holder(s) and admins that a change has occurred in the team's composition.

Comment: Are you sure about this? I tried to leave the team and there was no email like above. Both on enterprise and company accounts.

Answer (score 0):

I did it myself on our company account. After you left the Apple Developer Program of your team, there was **NO** email sent to the account holder or admin. And you will continue logging in on `appstoreconnect` for a couple of minutes (maybe the token takes some time to sync). Then you're automatically logged out with this kind of pop-up.

[image]